# How to generate JaCoCo xml reports in Gradle on Bamboo

Tags: sonarqube, bamboo, gradlew

I run SonarQube on Bamboo build with `gradlew` command:

```
./gradlew -Dsonar.projectKey="${PROJECT_KEY}" -Dsonar.projectName="${PROJECT_NAME}" -Dsonar.branch.name="${bamboo_planRepository_1_branch}" -Dsonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths=${TEST_REPORTS_PATH} :"${module}":testDebugUnitTest sonarqube
```

and there is no matter which `TEST_REPORTS_PATH` I use, I always get

> No coverage report can be found with sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths='build/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml'. Using default locations: target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml,target/site/jacoco-it/jacoco.xml,build/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml

and if I search for the report `xml` I don't find it. Under my `build` folder I have:

```
generated
intermediates
jacoco
kotlin
outputs
reports
test-results
tmp
```

`jacoco` has only `testDebugUnitTest.exec`

`reports` path is like `reports/tests/testDebugUnitTest` it which are:

```
classes
css
index.html
js
packages
```

so no report `xml`. Someone knows how I can force jacoco to create `xml` report?

Answer (score 1):

[JaCoCo plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html) provides an option to enable the XML report generation:

```
plugins {
    id 'jacoco'
}

jacoco {
    toolVersion = '0.8.9'
}

jacocoTestReport {
    reports.xml.required = true
}
```

Comment: jacocoTestReport() not found

Comment: Is the `JaCoCo` plugin applied/enabled? The `jacocoTestReport` task is provided by the plugin. If it is missing then it means that the plugin is not available.

Comment: yes, the plugin is applied. I can see the `.exec` created by jacoco, but no `.xml`. I added `jacoco` to gradle, but `jacocoTestReport()` not found.

Comment: I have this `jacocoTestReport { dependsOn test; reports.xml.enabled = true }` and it works. Add your `build.gradle` to the question, please.

Comment: Note, the property name is now "required" instead of "enabled" with jacoco 0.8.10 (and probably before as well)